# How to validate an element of a DropdownList with BootstrapValidator

Tags: jquery, bootstrapvalidator

Im using the 0.5.2 version of BootstrapValidator of nghuuphuoc and I want to validate if the user chosed another element rather than the first one.

This is the dropdown html:

```
<select class="form-control valid" id="DocumentType" name="DocumentType">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">DNI</option>
<option value="2">CI</option>
<option value="3">CUIT</option>
<option value="4">PASAPORTE</option>
</select>
```

The idea is to apply the bootstrap error classes when the user did not choose an option (different from "Select" or different from value=0)

Is there any way to achieve this with BootstrapValidator? Something like:

```
$('#msform').bootstrapValidator({
    // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        DocumentType: {
            validators: {
                <validation that check if 1st elemet is selected>: {
                    field: 'DocumentType',
                    message: 'Select an option ',
                },
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#msform').bootstrapValidator({
        // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        DocumentType: {
            validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Select an option !!'
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But the first element is not empty, it has a value of 0 with text in it.

Comment: it will not consider value=" " as valid answer. so you can define first option <option value=" ">Select</option>